# Why using -> operator used in Struct does not work in C

Tags: c, struct

I'm kind of new in C and I have thoroughly searched for an answer. Why -> operator does not compile in my code on a struct.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>

float t1=0.0f;
float t2=0.0f;
void main()
{
    int i;
    float a,t1,t2;
    struct timespec ts;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID,&ts);
    t1 =(float)ts->tv_sec;
    printf(" Tiempo 1 %f\n",t1);
    a=0;
    for (i=0;i<10000000;i++)
    {
        a+=1;
    }

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID,&ts);
    t2 = (float)ts -> tv_sec;
    printf(" Tiempo 2 %f\n",t2);
    printf(" Delta  %f\n",t2-t1);
    printf("%f\n",a);
}
```

Compile error:

```
c1.c: In function ‘main’:
c1.c:27:14: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘struct timespec’)
 t1 =(float)ts->tv_sec;
              ^
c1.c:37:15: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘struct timespec’)
 t2 = (float)ts->tv_sec;
```

I have seen ts.tv_sec works but I don not why -> does not work in main function and it does when it's inside a different funcion ... I'm kind of confused. I would really appreciate your help. 
Thanks

Comment: use `->` in case of pointers .

Comment: It's `int main(void)`, not `void main()`. Whoever advised you to use `void main()` does not know C very well. Find a better source of information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least in C, `ts->tv_sec` can be thought of as syntactic sugar for `(*ts).tv_sec`.

Since `ts` is not a pointer, your code does not compile. Just write `ts.tv_sec` instead.

> why -> does not work in main function and it does when it's inside a different funcion

Because that other function probably accesses a `timespec` through a pointer parameter?

Comment: Make me sense now. Thanks